# How can I print for loop data into a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set such as the following (this is only a subset in which the forloop might produce invalid results).

```
tableData <- data.frame(Fruits = character(), Ripeness = character(), Mean = numeric()) %>%
  add_row(Fruits = "Apple", Ripeness = "yes", Mean = 5) %>%
  add_row(Fruits = "Apple", Ripeness = "no", Mean = 6) %>%
  add_row(Fruits = "Apple", Ripeness = "yes", Mean = 2) %>%
  add_row(Fruits = "Banana", Ripeness = "yes", Mean = 1) %>%
  add_row(Fruits = "Banana", Ripeness = "yes", Mean = 7) %>%
  add_row(Fruits = "Orange", Ripeness = "no", Mean = 8)
```

The following for loop produces a t-test of the Mean for each category of fruits by their ripeness.

```
finalOut <- data.frame(Fruits = character(), Mean = numeric())
fruitLoop <- function(x) {
  fruit <- unique(x$Fruits)
  for(i in 1:length(fruit)){
    df<-filter(x, Fruits==fruit[i])
    fruit[i]
    ripe <- unique(df$Ripeness)
    if(length(ripe)<2) {
      next
    }
    tryResult <- tryCatch(
      {
        t.test(Mean ~ Ripeness, data = df)$p.value
      },
      error=function(cond){
      }
    )
    finalOut[i,] <- c(fruit[i],tryResult)
  }
}
```

I want the results of the t-test printed into the finalOut, however it doesn't seem to print into it. How can I achieve this? Again, the data is only a subset, and might be insufficient for the forloop to run.

Comment: Add `finalOut` or `return(finalOut)` at the end of your function call to specify what gets returned.

Comment: I have tried this, but it only returns the finalOut as a print, and does not have it stored into the finalOut data frame.

Comment: I misread your code, never mind my comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example data there's not enough observations to conduct a t.test, so I created a new example. You don't need a for loop, you can use `group_by` with `summarise` to get  a t-test of the Mean for each category of fruits by their ripeness.

```
library(dplyr)

tableData <- tibble(Fruits = sample(c('Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'), 30, T),
                        Ripeness = sample(c('yes', 'no'), 30, T),
                        Mean = ifelse(Ripeness == 'yes', 1.4 + runif(30), 1.6 + runif(30)))

tableData %>% 
  group_by(Fruits) %>% 
  summarise(t_test_pval = t.test(Mean ~ Ripeness)$p.value)
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   Fruits t_test_pval
#   <chr>        <dbl>
# 1 Apple        0.277
# 2 Banana       0.747
# 3 Orange       0.837
```

Example with `tryCatch`

```
tableData <- tibble(Fruits = sample(c('Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'), 30, T),
                        Ripeness = sample(c('yes', 'no'), 30, T),
                        Mean = ifelse(Ripeness == 'yes', 1.4 + runif(30), 1.6 + runif(30))) %>% 
 add_row(Fruits = "Peach", Ripeness = "yes", Mean = 5)

get_t_test_pval <- function(formula){
  tryCatch({t.test(formula)$p.value}, error = function(cond) NA)
}

tableData %>% 
  group_by(Fruits) %>% 
  summarise(t_test_pval = get_t_test_pval(Mean ~ Ripeness))

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   Fruits t_test_pval
#   <chr>        <dbl>
# 1 Apple        0.108
# 2 Banana       0.171
# 3 Orange       0.169
# 4 Peach       NA
```

Comment: Wow! That's much more concise. With that I could just plug the summarised results into another table right?

Comment: Yeah, you can add the `t_test_pval` column to another table with `left_join` (or with base R, `merge`). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: I just tried it and ran into another problem. I had the tryCatch in place because in the real set of data, there were still various fruits that only had one type of ripeness, or even not enough observations. Thus, the t-test wouldn't work on every single fruit? So it goes back to the original question of how to save the results from the for loop.

Comment: Added an example with `tryCatch`

Comment: Is it also possible to summarize a column that shows the mean difference (ie mean of yes ripeness - mean of no ripeness) to each fruit? (with trycatch enabled as well)?